# App crash caused by data binding related to java.lang.Runnable android.databinding.ViewDataBinding.mRebindRunnable

Tags: android-databinding

The exception is the following:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.Runnable android.databinding.ViewDataBinding.mRebindRunnable' on a null object reference
        at android.databinding.ViewDataBinding.access$100(ViewDataBinding.java:51)
        at android.databinding.ViewDataBinding$5.onViewAttachedToWindow(ViewDataBinding.java:142)
        at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:14525)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2836)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1364)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Let me try my best to make the description brief and clear.

First, this is related to a layout added dynamically.  The activity's data binding works perfectly without any problem.
Here is the layout foo_view:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="foo"
            type="net.mydomain.myapp.MyActivity.Foo" />
        <import type="android.view.View" />
    </data>
    <!--For the sake of debugging, no data binding is actually used-->
    ...
</layout>
```

In MyActivity.java:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public class Foo{
       ...
    }


   ...
   addFoo(){
       FooViewBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(this), R.layout.foo_view, myGridLayout, true); 
       Foo foo = new Foo();
       binding.setFoo(foo);  
   }
}
```

The app cashes immediately upon the start of MyActivity. The crash is not caused by a specific line of code.

Could anyone shed some light on this?

**[Edit] 2016-06-30**

The crash happens on a Lollipop, but same code works fine on a Jelly Bean

Comment: `myGridLayout` might be null, check for it.

Comment: @RRR No, it is not null. As I stated in my post: the crash is not caused by a specific line of code.

Comment: u found solution?

Comment: @Hong did you solve it?

Comment: @Tiberal  No, I have not solved the problem.  I abandoned the original approach and used a fragement instead.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case someone has the same problem, this errors occurs when you change the tag (i.e. `view.setTag(object)`) of a data-binding enabled view, as the data binding library uses the tag for itself.

Comment: What if i have to use setTag for pageTransformation in my Fragement of ViewPager along with data binding enabled?

Answer (score 0):

in my case,

If I use <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group/> in 'merge'it gives an error on some screens.

```
<merge tools:parentTag="androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
            android:id="@+id/constraint_group_active"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="@{data != null}"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="txt_offering_slogan,view_extra_gift,iv_offering,txt_offering_title,txt_offering_subtitle,txt_buy_extra_gift"
            tools:visibility="visible" />
</merge>
```